# Core data: Set Managed Object Context from AppDelegate for app with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I usually set the `managedObjectContext` for the root view using the following code in `AppDelegate.h`:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
HomeViewController *controller = (HomeViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

But my current application contains a custom `UITabBarController` at the root followed by a `UINavigationController` and then the `UIViewController`. How do I set the `managedObjectContext` to the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it very similar

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
// index 0 means left-most tab    
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)tabController.viewControllers[0];
HomeViewController *controller = (HomeViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Or, what I prefer:

In your HomeViewController do

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// somewhere (e. g. awakeFromNib, loadView or viewDidLoad)
self.managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext
```

And in your AppDelegate make `managedObjectContext` a public property.

Comment: Thanx! That worked. I had been trying `tabBController.selectedViewController` instead of `tabController.viewControllers[0]` all this time and it never worked out.